# chown illegal group name & getting Error for bower

Tags: json, node.js, macos, command-line, bower-install

In the command line when entering:

```
sudo chown joannak:joannak~/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json
```

I get

```
chown: joannak: illegal group name.
```

I am doing this because I am having an issue with trying to install anything with Bower. It keeps giving me this error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/joannak/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json'
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
You don't have access to this file.
```

I am working on a mac and am the administrator.
How can I fix this. Thanks for your help!

I updated the syntax and stopped getting the illegal group name with the following:

sudo chown joannak: ~/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json

I just need to verify if Bower is working now.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a space between joannak:joannak and ~/.config/configstore/... ?

Comment: I changed it to: sudo chown joannak: ~/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json and it responds to: Joannas-MBP:Documents joannak$ however when I enter= bower install jquery it answers = Stack trace:
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/joannak/.cache/bower/registry/bower.herokuapp.com/lookup/jquery_d223e'
    at Error (native)

Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:82:37).........

Comment: Please update your question with the error you get when executing `sudo chown joannak:joannak ~/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json 
`. It's not easy to read it in comment.

Comment: I updated the syntax and stopped getting the illegal group name with the following:

sudo chown joannak: ~/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json

I just need to verify if Bower is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I updated the syntax and stopped getting the illegal group name with the following:

```sh
sudo chown joannak: ~/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json
```

Comment: You can accept your own answers also. You only have to wait for 2 days to do so.